# spring-boot maven plugin re runs compile & test phase

Tags: maven-plugin, spring-boot

Using the spring-boot-maven-plugin both the run and repackage goal cause my compile and test stage to be re ran e.g.

```
mvn clean package spring-boot:run
```

and you see two compile and test runs...

in the maven debug out put I can see

```
...
[DEBUG] Goal:          org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:repackage (default)
[DEBUG] Style:         Regular
[DEBUG] Configuration: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <finalName default-value="${project.build.finalName}"/>
  <outputDirectory default-value="${project.build.directory}"/>
  <project default-value="${project}"/>
</configuration>
[DEBUG] --- init fork of myapp:1.0-SNAPSHOT for     org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.0.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) ---
[DEBUG] Dependencies (collect): []
[DEBUG] Dependencies (resolve): [compile, test]
[DEBUG] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And looking at the plugin source code classes, RunMojo amd RepackageMojo I see

```
@Mojo(name = "run", requiresProject = true, defaultPhase = LifecyclePhase.VALIDATE, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.TEST)
@Execute(phase = LifecyclePhase.TEST_COMPILE)
public class RunMojo extends AbstractMojo {
```

Thinking that the @Execute has something to do with it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Why don't you just use "mvn spring-boot:run"? As far as I know, that's just the way Maven works.

Comment: A better example is the repackage goal, by default it is attached to the maven verify stage (which itself ensures the previous phases compile, package etc have been completed). So if you run 'mvn clean install' you get phases clean > compile > test > package > verify > then spring-boot:repackage kicks off > compile > test > install...

Comment: It's the same story for that - you have to tie a Maven goal to a specific lifecycle phase. Normally you don't run spring-boot:repackage as a standalone goal, you tie it to the "package" lifecycle in your pom (the starter-parent does that for you), and then it doesn't need to re-execute the earlier goals.

Answer (score 0):

My bad...it is actually the cobertura plugin doing this which is understandable as it needs to recompile the source to instrument it for coverage.